# What does stdole.dll do?

Tags: c#, com, stdole

We have a large C# (.net 2.0) app which uses our own C++ COM component and a 3rd party fingerprint scanner library also accessed via COM. We ran into an issue where in production some events from the fingerprint library do not get fired into the C# app, although events from our own C++ COM component fired and were received just fine.

Using MSINFO32 to compare the loaded modules on a working system to those on a failing system we determined that this was caused by STDOLE.DLL not being in the GAC and hence not loaded into the faulty process.

Dragging this file into the GAC caused events to come back fine from the fingerprint COM library.

So what does stdole.dll do? It's 16k in size so it can't be much... is it some sort of link to another library like STDOLE32? How come its absence causes such odd behavior?

How do we distribute stdole.dll? This is an XCOPY deploy app and we don't use the GAC. Should we package it as a resource and use the System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish.GacInstall to ensure it's in the GAC?

Answer (score 25):

It seems that stdole.dll is a **primary interop assembly**. See [Office 2003 Primary Interop Assemblies on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195478(office.11).aspx)

Comment: Yes I found a copy in the PIA directory as well. Our app doesn't use office components; and this still doesn't explain the behavior we are seeing!

Comment: It may use a "standard" COM interface like IFont or IDispatch. Seems support for these interfaces in .NET need to ref stdole.dll. I'm confused why the heck this assembly is tied to Office.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is also discussed over here: [Why is Visual Studio 2015 adding stdole.dll and Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31970967/3347858)

Upgrading an older project to VS 2015 is what caused stdole.dll to start getting included in the project in this case.

If the library referencing has the option to "Embed Interop Types" in the properies, this is preferred and the stdole.dll may not be needed after that. Just set `Embed Interop Types=true` in the properties of the reference.

Libraries that allow this include the MS Office libraries such as Office, Excel, Core. An example of one that does not is Crystal Reports.

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant?tab=topactivity) **strongly discourages** setting `Embed Interop Types=false` here: [What's the difference setting Embed Interop Types true and false in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514240/whats-the-difference-setting-embed-interop-types-true-and-false-in-visual-studi)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think any of the other answers actually answered most of the question "what does `stdole.dll` do". Here's my understanding.

#### Summary:

This DLL is near the top of a chain of references leading from your managed application ultimately to unmanaged operating system DLLs which looks like this:

```plaintext
    .NET app -->
        stdole.dll -->
            stdole2.tlb -->
                oleaut32.dll
```

The links in this chain are well defined but obscure. The rest of this answer walks the chain...

---

#### Detailed explanation:

`stdole.dll` itself is an interop DLL. That means that it is a .NET assembly whose purpose is to essentially [act as a wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/com-callable-wrapper) around specific unmanaged classes which have COM interfaces. If you look inside `stdole.dll` with a tool like [ILSpy](http://%60%60%60lang-none) or dotPeek you can see what's there. Here's an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/additional-apis/stdole.stdpicture) for the `StdPicture` interface:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace stdole
{
  [CoClass(typeof (StdPictureClass))]
  [Guid("7BF80981-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB")]
  [ComImport]
  public interface StdPicture : Picture
  {
  }
}
```

All this is is an interface with attributes that encode details of the COM classes that *really* should be used. DLLs like this are generally created automatically with a tool like [`tlbimp.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer) or Visual Studio will do this for you when you add an unmanaged COM DLL directly to your project as a reference.

---

We can dig a little deeper. A `Guid` in the example above `7BF80981-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB` is generally going to be found in the Windows registry, that's where the runtime is going to look when `stole.StdPicture` is actually used from managed code.

If you search for that GUID using RegEdit, you'll find:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{7BF80981-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB}\TypeLib
```

which has the value    `00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046`.

Searching for that value, you'll find:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

(Most of the other GUIDs from the same DLL would probably have a similar entry).

This key has a lot of interesting details, in fact details for several versions of the underlying implementation. For instance under subkey   `2.0\0\win32`  the default value is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SysWow64\stdole2.tlb
```

for the 32-bit variant of version 2. That's one step closer to where `StdPicture` actually is implemented.

---

A TLB file is just a COM "header" of sorts for a DLL. It doesn't have executable code in itself. Opening `stdole2.tlb` in a tool like [OLEViewDotNet](https://github.com/tyranid/oleviewdotnet) or the original [OleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer), you can read the IDL of the typelib itself. In this case, the first part has the following:

```
// typelib filename: stdole2.tlb

[
  uuid(00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046),
  version(2.0),
  helpstring("OLE Automation")
]
library stdole
{
    ...
}
```

Note the `uuid` has the same value we got from Regedit above. Scrolling down eventually we come to the `StdPicture` entry, the same example as above:

```
[
  uuid(0BE35204-8F91-11CE-9DE3-00AA004BB851)
]
coclass StdPicture {
    ...
};
```

---

Yet again there's no real code here, just a class definition. Back to RegEdit we can find that `uuid`:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0BE35204-8F91-11CE-9DE3-00AA004BB851}\InprocServer32
```

whose value is `C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll`. Now we know that this DLL implements the `StdPicture` coclass for version 2 of the 32-bit `stdole` library.

(Though I would have thought this file should be in `SysWow64`...?)

If you were to follow this chain for some other interface, you might end up at the same DLL or another.

Note that for some languages (like VB6) it is typical for the TLB to be embedded right in the implementing DLL directly. But this is not required for COM and obviously not how Microsoft did it in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I just deleted the reference from the application and recompiled. Ran all the tests which passed. Then redeployed without the dll and it all worked.

I dont know how a reference to this got in the project in the first place. It is a legacy app so must have been a long time ago.

Simon

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was an old unused reference to Office Word Interop ... but removing that was not sufficient: The publish profile still had line to copy stdole.dll !

```
<File Include="bin/stdole.dll"> ...
```

Deleting that line (found using 'Find in Files') and deleting the stdole.dll from the bin folder on the remote server fixed my problem.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had to also add a reference to my project for stdole.  Even though I don't have any references to it (it's a simple image app), 2 of our users were getting errors that it was missing.  It could be that they were only running .net 2.0 when this is a 3.5 app.  I have figured out why.

I also went in to publish on the project properties tab, and selected Application Files, then included the stdole to be deployed.  Hopefully that will work.

Comment: It might work, but stdole.dll is not a redistributable file and could break existing installations according to this...(search for stdole) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195478(office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In our project IDispatch couses using stdole.dll. We've change it to object and remove IDispatch, then remove stdole from references.