# Why is Visual Studio 2015 adding stdole.dll and Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll to my project?

Tags: dll, reference, visual-studio-2015

These DLLs are not added to my project in prior versions of Visual Studio. My guess is that one of my references has a dependency to these DLLs. From what I've read, the highlighted `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` might be the one. Can anyone confirm this? I should also note that VS 2015 always publishes these DLLs as well even if I exclude them from the the project. If I delete them, VS 2015 will remake them.

**Edit**: I have confirmed that the Excel and Office references are what's causing the inclusion of stdole.dll. See selected answer below to remove stdole.dll.

I've crossed out the custom references. Let me know if more information is needed. Here's my current references:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about that? My first downvote. A downvote with no feedback is highly unproductive.

Comment: I'm interested in this question, because stdole.dll is poping up on all apps that I do.  I publish with click-once and it's causing failures with visual studio 2015.  It may be unrelated to this question, but other people may find this question searching for that dll.  This other guy he replaced it with a signed copy in his: https://iznum.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/strong-name-signature-not-valid-for-this-assembly-stdole-dll/

Comment: Another guy posted a bug about this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1658072/could-not-load-assembly-file-stdole-dll-that-were-not-actually-using

Comment: @249076 I'm guessing that your apps have references where "Embed Interop Types"=false and maybe it's showing up now after an upgrade to VS2015. I've updated my answer below which might help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have the option, use Embed Interop Types and leave stdole.dll out of it all together or you will run into the problem every time you move the application (new servers or dev machines) where stdole.dll isn't signed.

**Problem:** There is a reference that is requiring stdole.dll and stdole.dll is now being automatically pushed to the bin folder.

**Solution:**

- Find the reference requiring stdole.dll (more on how to do this below)
- Go to it's properties (Right click->properties)
- Change "Embed Interop Types" from false to true.

**How to find the reference:** When you click on the properties of your references, check to see if "Embed Interop Types" is set to false. To dig even further, [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37995248/3347858) has some great info.

**References I've confirmed so far that use stdole.dll** (probably more office programs as well)

- Office
- Excel
- Core
- Crystal Reports (Thanks Lithium. As Nick points out, you may not have the advantage of setting `Embed Interop Types=true`)
- NetOffice OfficeApi

If you find more, add them to this list or note them in the comments and I'll do it.

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant?tab=topactivity) **strongly discourages** setting `Embed Interop Types=false` here: [What's the difference setting Embed Interop Types true and false in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514240/whats-the-difference-setting-embed-interop-types-true-and-false-in-visual-studi)

Scott Hanselman also talks about what the "Embed Interop Types" does here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CLRAndDLRAndBCLOhMyWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. You can add Crystal Reports dlls to the list of references that use stdole.dll

Comment: I've also found that the NetOffice OfficeApi library requires stdole.dll - this is (most likely) because it is leveraging the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library in the background :)

Answer (score 26):

As others indicated, `stdole.dll` is a Primary Interop Assembly for a bunch of Office COM interop components. You can determine why it's getting included in your project by doing the following.

In Visual Studio, go to `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run`.  Change the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting to `Detailed`.  Now clean and rebuild your project.

Open the Output window and search for `stdole`.  You should find a section like this:

```
25>  Dependency "stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
25>      Resolved file path is "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common\stdole.dll".
25>      Reference found at search path location "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
25>          For SearchPath "D:\Git\FoobarServices\Dependencies\Dependencies".
25>          Considered "D:\Git\FoobarServices\Dependencies\stdole.winmd", but it didn't exist.
25>          Considered "D:\Git\FoobarServices\Dependencies\stdole.dll", but it didn't exist.
25>          Considered "D:\Git\FoobarServices\Dependencies\stdole.exe", but it didn't exist.
25>          For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".
25>          Considered "Dependencies\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but its name "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" didn't match.
25>          Considered "Dependencies\CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework.dll", but its name "CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework" didn't match.
25>          Considered "Dependencies\CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore.dll", but its name "CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore" didn't match.
25>          Considered "Dependencies\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll", but its name "CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" didn't match.
25>          Considered "Dependencies\CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll", but its name "CrystalDecisions.Shared" didn't match.
25>          Considered "Dependencies\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll", but its name "CrystalDecisions.Web" didn't match.
25>          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
25>          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\stdole.winmd", but it didn't exist.
25>          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\stdole.dll", but it didn't exist.
25>          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\stdole.exe", but it didn't exist.
25>          For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
25>          Considered AssemblyFoldersEx locations.
25>      Required by "CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
25>      Required by "CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
25>      Required by "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
25>      Required by "CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304".
25>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v1.0.3705".
```

You can see where Visual Studio searched for the assembly as well what requires it at the bottom.  In my case it's a bunch of old Crystal Reports assemblies.

Sometimes you can embed the interop types via the dependencies as Tony suggests, but not always.  For me, the Crystal Reports assemblies do not support this.

I fixed this problem (and the insidious one scottsanpedro mentioned) by copying the `stdole.dll` (32KB, digitally signed) from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\` into a "Dependencies" folder inside my project.  I added the file to my project and added an explicit reference to it (Add Reference > Browse).  Finally I opened the new reference's properties and set `Embed Interop Types` to `True`.

This seems to be a better situation.  I shouldn't need to worry about getting an unsigned version of the assembly.

Comment: Good info, Nick. I'm going to refer to your answer in my answer on finding which classes refer to the dll.

Comment: If you set `Embed Interop Types` to `True`, is there still a need to stdole.dll? My app no longer needs it.

Answer (score 9):

I have been dealing with this problem for ages.

Whenever I install anything from the web platform or any updates the stdole.dll gets replaced with a non signed version. I reported the bug to Microsoft a while back but fell on deaf ears.

I go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies and copy the signed version (22kb) from here and replace the version in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common (16kb) and that solves the problem.

Scott

Comment: Scott, I found a way to do this without messing around with the stdole.dll anymore. Just updated my answer. Still voted you up because you gave me another workaround.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation I found that toggling the Copy Local property of the assembly that depends on stdole.dll, saving the project and then toggling the property back to its original value, and finally saving the project again solved the problem.  This property may also be related to the Embed Interop Types property for other people with this problem.

What this does is explicitly saves the Copy Local property to the .xxproj file.  Otherwise, the state of this property is not in the project file and a default is assumed.  I have no explanation why this works as the presence of the property in the project file does not change the displayed value in Visual Studio nor does it cause a change in the assembly actually being published or not.  I also did not cause a change in these properties from their originally displayed values after toggling them back and forth.

I do note that even before I found the cure I saw that cleaning the project and rebuilding it did not cause stdole.dll to be copied to bin.  It was only after publishing that stdole.dll showed up.

Comment: Good info. Now you have me wondering if I removed a reference that was set to `Copy Local` and the reference I re-added was not.

Comment: Your instinct was correct on "Embed Interop Types". I've found the issue and updated my answer.